# iOS tabbar not work with push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    TabBarController *tabBarController = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[SearchPageControllerViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, vc2, nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
}
```

[image]

I use push segue connection, i have got tab bar but when i change screen with push segue tab bar get invis how can fix this problem i added this code part but now worked any idea ?

Check images for more info...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not checked the "Hide bottom bar on push" option on the Attribute Inspector of the view controllers on Storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To avoid tabbar from disappearing while changing viewController I would used presentViewController, and dismissViewController instead.

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testview"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];

UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootVC"];
[self dismissViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```